# Boxnet return ID File negative

Tags: box-api

When I try to download a file with API v1.0 the files ID is negative and returns the next message:

"no such file"

But I get the name, info, and the other info.
This happens only in some files.

Comment: Which language do you use? Show tour vide for reading the ID.

Comment: Tour vide = your code (autocorrect...)

Answer (score 0):

Box file IDs can be into 'big int' territory i.e. > 2^32. It's not recommended that your store File IDs in integer data structures, rather you should store them as strings to avoid any issues overflow issues.